# How to check whether csv.DictReader object is empty or not

Tags: python, csv

I am writing python code to read contents from a csv file with the DictReader.

```
with open(parafile, "rb") as paracsv:         
    #Read in parameter values as a dictionary
    paradict = csv.DictReader(paracsv)
    if paradict.line_num <= 1:
        return None
```

I want to be able to return immediately if there is no more than one row read from the csv file.

I have tried checking the line_num, but it always returns 0 even there are more than one row in the file. Does anyone know what is the correct/efficient way to check this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, without reading lines, know how many there are in the file. Note that the [`csvreader.line_num` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num) reflects the number of lines *read so far*, not the number of lines present in the file:

> The number of lines read from the source iterator. This is not the same as the number of records returned, as records can span multiple lines.

Just read your file; if there is only one row in the file, you'll end up returning early *anyway*.

If you only return `None` if there were no rows read, you could use:

```
with open(parafile, "rb") as paracsv:         
    #Read in parameter values as a dictionary
    paradict = csv.DictReader(paracsv)
    has_rows = False
    for line in paradict:
        has_rows = True

    if not has_rows:
        return None
```

If there are no rows beyond the first header row in the file, this returns *early*, as the for loop immediately terminates.

Comment: I also tried "if paradict.next() == None". The problem with that is later on when I am trying to loop through the rows, it starts from the second row.

Comment: @edjie: Exactly. And you'd have to use `next(paradict, None) is None`; if the file is empty then your version raises `StopIteration`. Why do you need to return early? If the first row is headers, then `DictReader` will read that first, and the subsequent loop won't iterate anyway.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. You are right, now going through my code again, I realize I don't need to return early.